# How to make allow alphabets only for a text field, validating on "OnClick" event? Please correct me what i am doing wrong with my script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dear Sir i want to use this code for alphabet only.This code not working i need your help please correct my code i am unable to find the error why it creating problem.I am hoping kind reply for correct code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#FullName').bind("cut copy paste drag drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="FullName" id="FullName" required>
```

Comment: I don't understand what this code should do, the function `isNumberKey` is never used

Comment: Sir this code actually work with number filed and restrict on click when some one enter alphabet. Now i wanna to change this function for alphabet

Comment: Also, you can use regex instead of charcodes

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: (Without to write any function)

```
  <input type="text" name="onlyalphabet" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || (event.charCode == 32)">
```

Comment: This code working fine but not allow space between name i.g johan doe it take it as johandoe.

Comment: Updated my solution, now it will accept space too :)

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the problem it sounds like you're trying to restrict the value entered to only alphabetic characters, and also `.` and spaces. As such you need to hook to the `input` event of the element. From there you can use a regex to remove invalid characters. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#FullName').on("input", function(e) {
    $(this).val((i, v) => v.replace(/[^a-z \.]/gi, ''));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="FullName" id="FullName" required>
```

As an aside, note that `bind()` was deprecated a long time ago and should not be used. `on()` is best practice now.

Comment: $(this).val((i, v) => v.replace(/[^a-z \.]/gi, '')); in this line where "=>" it generate syntax error.please help me out in this regard.

Comment: I guess you're using IE if you get that error. In that case, use this: `$(this).val(function(i, v) { return v.replace(/[^a-z \.]/gi, '') });`

Answer (score 0):

Without space

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#FullName').bind("cut copy paste drag drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="FullName" id="FullName"  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"  required>
```

With Space

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#FullName').bind("cut copy paste drag drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || charCode == 32)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="FullName" id="FullName"  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"  required>
```